# Pimcore installation on webserver

Tags: pimcore, pimcore-v5

I started to test the new Pimcore during the last few days. I realized, you can't install Pimcore with the common vendor/bin/pimcore-install command anymore. So how I am supposed to install Pimcore on my webserver after I loaded the files via FTP to the server.

Do I need a SSL connection? If this is the case, I have to switch me provider.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need a SSH connection to run the needed install commands via the CLI.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a SSL connection but you do need CLI terminal in order to you PHP-CLI commands and PIMCore CLI commands in your web server.